# Do you allow somebody do something?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say "I allowed my son go to the movies" instead of "I allowed my son **to** go to the movies"?

Comment: In short, no. :)

Comment: From Google: "I allowed my son to go to the movies": About 6,630,000,000 results (0.68 seconds) "I allowed my son go to the movies": No results found. You could also compare "allowed my son to go" with "allowed my son go" on an Ngram. But you should be doing this yourself - this site is not intended to replace a bit of easy work by the enquirer.

Comment: Bare infinitival clauses are used with modals and verbs of perception, and not with many other ones. There's a brief coverage of it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Bare_infinitive). Now, why that is so, I am not really sure. Would love to know.

Comment: There are almost certainly reasons, probably lost in the mists of time, so that the term 'idiosyncratic' is applicable nowadays. 'Let' of course perversely takes a bare infinitive: "I let my son go to the movies" **not** "I let my son to go to the movies". 'Help' and base forms of 'come', 'go' can be used with catenating base forms. The semi-modal 'dare' takes base forms in some but not all reasonably-to-be-expected constructions.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on [ell.se].

Comment: @Edwin: *I **let/saw/heard/etc.** my son go...* I don't know why *some* verbs accept a "bare infinitive" in such contexts, but it's probably fair to say *most* don't. Off-hand, ***help*** is the only one I can think of where it seems to be just a stylistic choice whether to include the "infinitive marker" ***to*** or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes – Talia mentioned these. 'Dare' sometimes offers the choice (_Do you dare (to) go to the graveyard after midnight?_ but ?? _Don't dare sleep in the graveyard_ ).

Answer (score 14):

As a rule of thumb, if a verb allows an [object infinitive complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/comps.pdf) without *to*,
then it's very likely to be a short verb of Germanic origin.
(Basically, these are the ones that have been around for long enough to get their edges worn off)

E.g, *let, make, have, go, come, see, hear, watch*

A verb like *allow*, which comes from French, is excluded,
even though it means the same thing as *let*.
So *allow* requires the infinitive complementizer *to*
with an infinitive complement, while *let* does not even allow it.

- *He allowed me to inspect the seal.*
- **He allowed me inspect the seal.*
  but
- **He let me to inspect the seal.*
- *He let me inspect the seal.*

---

> *An asterisk `*` before an example sentence indicates that the sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: Great answer. I am so glad I grew up speaking English - I  would never be able to memorize grammar that is so unpredictable.

Comment: You already did, painlessly, just by having fun. That's what real grammar does for you. But languages are not designed to be learned easily by outsiders; on the contrary, usually. Unless multilingualism is the norm, as it is in many culture areas (e.g, highland New Guinea, pre-1492 N.America). But in those cases, where everybody already knows half a dozen languages, picking up a new one is much less of a problem, because you get the hang after a while, especially in a Sprachbund. It makes one very aware of language; much like studying linguistics.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is from Old French *alouer* ("to grant"). It is here twice transitive for the recipient and the thing, but "to go to ..." is considered as a whole, and you can't suppress the first *to*.

It is still very common in French but written *allouer*: *Une pension est allouée aux retraités*. ("A benefit is granted to retired people.")

The same word was used with the meaning "approve of."

It is still very common in French but became *louer*: *Il loue ces succès*. ("He praises these achievements.")